# ¿Cómo guardar datos en una relación has_many through desde una API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, relaciones

Estoy haciendo una API en Ruby on Rails, tengo dos modelos `plans` y `categories` los cuales hacen una relación muchos a muchos por lo tanto hago uso de una tabla intermedia con el modelo `category_plans`, la idea es que se cree un plan el cual tiene varias categorias y cada una de ellas tiene dos atributos más (`kind`, `portion`) los cuales se guardan en la tabla intermedia (Estoy usando Postgresql).

**Category**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :category_plans
    has_many :plan, through: :category_plans
end
```

**Plan**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :category_plans
    has_many :category, through: :category_plans
end
```

**CategoryPlan**

```
class CategoryPlan < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :category, :plan

    enum kind: {
        Colacion: 'Colacion',
        Desayuno: 'Desayuno',
        Comida: 'Comida',
        Cena: 'Cena'
    }, _prefix: :kind

    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :plan
end
```

Las migraciones son las siguientes

**Plan**

```
class CreatePlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        create_table :plans do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.references :patient, foreign_key: true
            t.text :description
            t.datetime :deleted_at
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

**Category**

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        create_table :categories do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

**CategoryPlan**

```
class CreateCategoryPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def up
        execute <<-SQL
            CREATE TYPE type_food AS ENUM ('Colacion', 'Desayuno', 'Comida', 
            'Cena');
        SQL

        create_table :category_plans do |t|
            t.belongs_to :category, :null => false, :index => true
            t.belongs_to :plan, :null => false, :index => true
            t.column :kind  , :type_food
            t.float :portion
        end
        add_index :category_plans, :kind
    end

    def down
        drop_column :kind, :type_food
        execute "DROP kind type_food;"
    end
end
```

Y el controlador

```
class V1::PlansController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_plan, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    def create
        plan = Plan.new(plan_params)
        if plan.save
            render json: {status: 'Success', message: 'Saved plan', data: 
            plan}, status: 201
        else
            render json: {status: 'Error', message: 'Plan not saved', data: 
            plan.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def plan_params
        params.require(:plan).permit(:name, :patient_id, :description, 
        category_plans_attributes: [:id, :kind, :portion, 
        category_attributes: [:id]])
    end

end
```

No estoy seguro que el strong params este correcto y tampoco tengo mucha idea de como armar mi JSON, al momento lo tengo así

**JSON**

```
{
    "plan": {
        "name": "Plan 8",   
        "patient_id": "3",
        "description": "Plan nuevo",
        "category_plan": {
            "kind": "Cena",
            "portion": "12.3"
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo unos cuantos errores, lo primero es que las relaciones `has_many` por convención deben ir en plural:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :category_plans
    has_many :plans, through: :category_plans
end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :category_plans
    has_many :categories, through: :category_plans
end
```

Lo otro es que si piensas asociar categorías a través de tu clase de planes, en tu modelo `Plan` deberías agregar `accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_plans`.
Luego tu strong parameter debería ser algo como:

```
  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(
      :name, :patient_id, :description,
      category_plans_attributes: [:kind, :portion, :category_id]
    )
  end
```

Y finalmente tu json:

```
{
    "plan": {
        "name": "Plan 8",   
        "patient_id": "3",
        "description": "Plan nuevo",
        "category_plans_attributes": {
            "kind": "Cena",
            "portion": "12.3",
            "category_id": "1"
          }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy me soluciono el problema